# RewriteRule is creating new URLs but not redirecting them from the dynamic ones

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

My website http://www.musicea.com.au has dynamic URLs. I have used .htaccess to rewrite the static URLs. When I copy the rewritten static urls and paste directly in the browser they open. But they are not redirecting automatically. My code is as given below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page-([0-9]+)\$ content.php?pageid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^$ content.php?pageid=home
RewriteRule ^about$ content.php?pageid=1341369117 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^music-lessons$ content.php?pageid=1344314997 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^piano-lessons$ content.php?  pageid=1347926925&getsubnavid=1344314997 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^keyboard-lessons$ content.php?pageid=1347927089&getsubnavid=1344314997 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^guitar-lessons$ content.php?pageid=1347927135&getsubnavid=1344314997 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^violin-lessons$ content.php?pageid=1347927198&getsubnavid=1344314997 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^content.php?pageid=home$ http://www.musicea.com.au/ [L,NC]
```

I think the URLs are rewritten properly but there's problem in redirecting.
Please suggest me.

Comment: which ones aren't working and how are you entering them in the browser? I can tell you the last one will not because rewriterule ignore the query string in the pattern. In your first rule don't escape $ either.

Comment: Everything I have rewritten is working manually. For example when I put http://www.musicea.com.au/music-lessons manually, the url opens. But it is not redirected automatically from the dynamic one:  http://www.musicea.com.au/content.php?pageid=1344314997. Please ignore the last one. I will remove it.

Comment: That's because you have no rule telling it to do so. You must create a rule so that if they put in the old URL it will redirect to new one.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell me how can I do this? It would be great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of what I meant in the comments. You only have a rule to internally rewrite to your PHP file, but you don't have a rule to redirect the use of the php file directly. So I'll show you an example of how to do that. I did one rule so that you can see. But because all your URI's don't have any mapping to your dynamic URL you will have to do a similar rule for each one of you rules.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page-([0-9]+)\$ content.php?pageid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^$ content.php?pageid=home
RewriteRule ^about$ content.php?pageid=1341369117 [L,NC]

#redirect direct request for content.php for music lesson
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} [A-Z]{3,}\ /content\.php\?pageid=1344314997
RewriteRule ^ /music-lessons? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^music-lessons$ content.php?pageid=1344314997 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^piano-lessons$ content.php?  pageid=1347926925&getsubnavid=1344314997 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^keyboard-lessons$ content.php?pageid=1347927089&getsubnavid=1344314997 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^guitar-lessons$ content.php?pageid=1347927135&getsubnavid=1344314997 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^violin-lessons$ content.php?pageid=1347927198&getsubnavid=1344314997 [L,NC]
```

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Thanks Jack. It works. It was indeed a great help. Thanks for your time.